# How many times does the function $y=x+\sin^2\left(\frac x3\right)-3$ cross the x-axis?

Tags: functions

How many times does the function $y=x+\sin^2(\frac x3)-3$ cross the x-axis?

by graphing the function, it's clear that it crosses x-axis at one point

But I'd like to do that algebraically

when the function crosses the x-axis, $y$=0 So we set our function to zero

$y=x+\sin^2\left(\frac x3\right)-3=0$

trying to factor this seems impossible !

Is there another way

Note : I am more interested on how many times it crosses the x-axis rather than in knowing the points themselves.

Comment: Hint: use Intermediate Value Theorem to show there is at least one solution, then use Rolle's Theorem to prove it's unique.

Comment: @Maher Do you know some calculus?

Comment: there exists a unique solution

Comment: @Edward Well, If I basically don't know how many times $f$ cross x-axis, how to figure out that there is only one point ?

Comment: @ahaan Of course I do !

Comment: @Maher Just find one solution with brute force, then prove it's unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the second term is always between $0$ and $1$, the reverse triangle inequality tells us that $|y(x)| \geq |x-3|-1$, so $|y(x)|$ can only be zero if $|x-3| \leq 1$, i.e. if $x \in [2,4]$.

Now the intermediate value theorem on $[2,4]$ tells you that there indeed is a solution, since $y(2)=2-3+\sin(2/3)^2<0$, $y(4)=4-3+\sin(4/3)^2>0$ and $y$ is continuous.

Now when you differentiate you get

$$y'(x)=1+\frac{2}{3} \sin(x/3) \cos(x/3)$$

You have $y' > 0$ since $\sin$ and $\cos$ are both between $-1$ and $1$. So this is actually an increasing function, and so there can only be one solution.